# <Title> doesn't behave like it should (I think) in HTML5

Tags: html, tags

I am learning HTML5 (so don't judge me) and I came across something that doesn't make much sense to me.

How come that when I put the title after the meta bit [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MqaU1.jpg), it doesn't become a title and somehow acts like it is in the body and not the head. If I put the title before the meta bit [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XMrBD.jpg), it works as it is supposed to.

Hope you didn't have a stroke reading this as I am a beginner and not even close to good at explaining things. I'm also new to this website btw.

Many thanks,
Nathan

Comment: Please read [ask], don't post pictures of text, and use [a validator](https://validator.nu/) which would probably have helped you identify your typo (a missing `>` on the previous line).

Comment: This is caused by a simple typo, your Meta Description Tag has no closing bracket.

Answer (score 0):

Its just a typo in your code, and kindly add your code in text format and refrain from adding pictures of your code.

Just close the meta tag on line 5 of your code and you're good to go.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="description" content="This is an awesome website">
    <title>Welcome!</title>
  </head>
  <body> 
    <h1>POG WEBSITE!</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```